# Can you use a NOT on Set Contains method?

Tags: apex, conditional

Is it OK to use a NOT on (negate) a `Set.contains()` method, or should I use an `if/else`, or does it not really matter?

**Use NOT on `contains()`:**

```
if (!psxAssigneeIds.contains(cgm.MemberId)) {
    cgUsersToDeleteSet.add(cgm);
}
```

**or is it better to use `else`:**

```
if (psxAssigneeIds.contains(cgm.MemberId)) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    cgUsersToDeleteSet.add(cgm);
}
```

or would both work equally well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to negate the `contains` result.

```
Boolean isValueNotInSet = !someSet.contains(someValue);
```

Notice, however, that it is not necessary to check for yourself if the `Set` already contains a value when adding to it. Straight from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm):

> **add(setElement)**
>   Adds an element to the set *if it is not already present.*

Comment: And if you want to be really pedantic just do `if (someSet.contains(someValue) == false)`

Comment: Yeah...I am not a fan of comparing `Boolean` values to each other instead of just evaluating them, but that's just me. @BorisBachovski

Answer (score 7):

Don't do either: when adding to a set, the values are automatically deduplicated.

```
// Adds the value if not already present in the set.
cgUsersToDeleteSet.add(cgm);
```

Also, there's a convenient method called `removeAll` that lets you avoid doing the initial IF statements. You could use it like this:

```
cgUsersToDeleteSet.addAll(memberIds);
cgUsersToDeleteSet.removeAll(assigneeIds);
```

Comment: When adding, it is true that you don't need to check. There are definitely contexts where you do want to though!

Comment: @AdrianLarson For a map, there's times where you need to check, but for a set, there's never a situation where you need to check for an existing value first (not that I've seen; I'd love to see a counterexample).

Comment: Not during the adding process, I mean there are valid use cases for `Set.contains`. Whitelisting, for example.

Comment: In this case, I've got a set of assigneeIds from a permission set, and a set of chatter group members from a chatter group. If the cgmember memberID is not in the set of permission set assignee ids, then I need to do something. Something being add the chattergroupmember to a list of records to delete. So I'm not checking if the record is already in the set I'm adding to, but I'm comparing the two and then taking action, on the negative scenario. Prob many better ways but that's what v2 is for!

Comment: @gorav I just realized you were using two sets. As an alternative, you might also look at `allAll`/`removeAll` to avoid using IF statements unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, if this were two sets of ids remove all would work BC the only cgmembers left would be ones that need to be deleted. But as I'm comparing a sobject.id to a set of IDs in a for loop, I would need to instead create a set of ids to compare and then go through a for loop to populate a list of records to delete, right? Or can you do a delete operation on a set of IDs?

Comment: Well I'll be...you can do a delete operation on a list of IDs.  Not sure if that works on sets too but easy enough to go from set to list!  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm

Comment: @gorav It's really easy to convert lists to sets and sets to list using constructors. There are some nifty ways to optimize Salesforce with a bit of effort.

Comment: Thanks, got much more out of this question and the comments than I anticipated!  Both answers are great.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: if you don't wanna add it but just wanna check if the current value is present in a predefined set, then you need the contains method.